# app crashes first time only not in second time in app purchase ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app crashes first time only when buying with in app purchase
but when app run second time it is not crashing. 
I am getting:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x11f3)

I have searched but not getting solution for this. Even I have used following dealloc method :-

```
-(void)dealloc 
{

    sharedInstance.productsRequest.delegate = nil;
    sharedInstance.productsRequest = nil;

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:sharedInstance];

}
```

My code where getting this crash is :-

```
-(void)purchaseItem:(SKProduct *)product {

     NSLog(@";Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    if (product == nil) {
        [self noProductsFound];
    } else {

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];// here getting the crash warning...

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: what is the console output in first run ?

Comment: @Zubair  , nothing come in console , just EXC_BAD_ACCESS is coming .  I am getting crash report as follows:-Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x024170b2 objc_msgSend + 14
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x02673529 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
2   com.apple.StoreKit             0x0077b297 -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 158
3   com.apple.StoreKit             0x0077956f -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 369

Comment: did you add `addTransactionObserver` to payment queue?

Comment: yes i have added , Mr. Zubair , app is crashing only first time with in app purchase , when running again it is not crashing and i can purchase.

Comment: place a break point at this line `if (product == nil)` and check what is `product` contains ?

Comment: i have same problem but not getting any solution. You got any solution?